# Webpack SASS @import with tilde path suddenly stopped working

Tags: import, webpack, node-sass

I'm using Webpack to compile SASS and was using import paths starting with the tilde (`~`) sign. This has been working all the time, but suddenly today, it stopped working.

I have reset my code in Git to a revision that was working Friday, but now I get an error.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this at all - should I change the `node-sass` version? Can anyone assist me?

Error:

```
error  in ./src/components/top-menu/style.scss

Module build failed:
@import "~sass/base";
^
File to import not found or unreadable: ~sass/base.
Parent style sheet: stdin
  in /path/to/stuff/src/components/top-menu/style.scss (line 1, column 1)
```

Comment: did you upgrade webpack from 1 to 2/3?

Comment: Maybe... I currently have 3.4.1.

Comment: In webpack 2 and 3 you don't need to add tilde (~) for less files to treat them as modules (so that module petcock is automatically tried)

Comment: `File to import not found or unreadable: sass/bootstrap.` :(

Comment: @HelgeTalvikSöderström did you ever reslove this?

Comment: Sorry, @lucas :( I simply started using ugly relative import paths until we recently started to work on a Flutter system instead.

Comment: No problem! My issue was my dumb mistake: my stylesheets weren't actually being compiled by webpack like I thought they were. Had to move them into my webpack assets directory and add a stylesheet_pack_tag to the site header.